# Why does Rails implement the method String#starts_with? rather than alias to start_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

Ruby on Rails has the method `String#starts_with?`, which is implemented in Ruby with

```
# File lib/active_support/core_ext/string/starts_ends_with.rb, line 22
def starts_with?(prefix)
  prefix = prefix.to_s
  self[0, prefix.length] == prefix
end
```

whereas Ruby, since version 1.8.7, has the method `String#start_with?`, which is implemented in C

```
static VALUE
rb_str_start_with(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE str)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        VALUE tmp = rb_check_string_type(argv[i]);
        if (NIL_P(tmp)) continue;
        rb_enc_check(str, tmp);
        if (RSTRING_LEN(str) < RSTRING_LEN(tmp)) continue;
        if (memcmp(RSTRING_PTR(str), RSTRING_PTR(tmp), RSTRING_LEN(tmp)) == 0)
            return Qtrue;
    }
    return Qfalse;
}
```

Why don't they just have an alias linking from `starts_with?` to `start_with?`?

Do they wish to maintain compatibility with Ruby 1.8.6, or are they worried that `start_with?` may have different behavior to `starts_with?`, or have they not seen the need to update the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you have a really old version of Rails at hand (<= 2.3.5). As this version supported older Ruby versions, which didn't yet had `start_with?` they implemented it by hand.

However if you look above in the file, you see that they used the ruby built-in method if it is available. In newer Rails versions where the Ruby 1.8.6 support was dropped, these magic bits [were removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c0bb4c6ed2f5a5676569746e7bfd70405346ef8f#activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/starts_ends_with.rb) and ActiveSupport now provides unconditional aliases.

Comment: I was looking at http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/StartsEndsWith.html - is that documentation out of date?

Comment: Yes, go to http://as.rubyonrails.org and you'll see it's from 2008. The current site to use is http://api.rubyonrails.org

Comment: Ouch.  Documentation fail.  Would be nice if the old site wrapped every request in a frame that says it is out of date...